# binary compare two files, failing only if first never matches any part of the second

Tags: file-comparison

I have a file (call it *A*, for reference) that may be a fragment of some other extant file on my system. I can't use `cmp` because I don't know how many bytes may be missing from the start of *A* (or, at least, I can't use it without brute forcing through the -i flag). Is there a way for me to discover whether *A* is already existent on my system (using GNU tools, or any other linux program)? Or will I have to botch together a c++ program to do the job? Note: efficiency is desirable since the files that *A* has to be compared with may be numerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing how big the chunk (*A*) is ... have you considered grep'ing for its content using **-a**?

Comment: `echo -e "\x00\x11\x22\x33" > file; echo -e "\x00\x11" > snip; grep -a snip file` doesn't seem to work

Comment: No, I hadn't considered grep! That'll do.

Comment: @warl0ck: grep needs a pattern, so try `grep -a "$(cat snip)" file`. But, shouldn't there be a problem with `echo`'s newlines? Your example should fail regardless of this correction, shouldn't it? On my system it succeeds...

Comment: In fact, why use `grep -a` at all? Can't I just use `grep`? Taking warl0ck's example, `echo -e "\x00\x11\x22\x33" > file; echo -e "\x00\x11Surplus Gibberish" > snip; grep -a "$(cat snip)" file` succeeds. Is that expected behaviour? If I remove the -a flag, then the command fails, as I'd want it to.

Comment: I'd be surprised if that worked.  Neither of snip or file is wholly included in the other in your example; I wouldn't expect a match, no matter what method of invocation.